# Copying some files from mypc to a host using winscp

Tags: suse, file-transfer

I have SUSE Linux Enterprise Server (SP 3), am trying to install the MZ 510 driver by copying the files on my pc to the directory on the server, i get permission denied. Which command should i use to have the read and write permission so i can upload my files.

Comment: You say in the title that you are using winscp to copy the files, but you don't mention where on the SuSE system you try to put them, or why.

Comment: am trying to copy files on the root directory, as i mentioned i want to upgrade the NIC driver

Comment: And I suspect you are not logging in as the root user? Why not copy the files to an ordinary user's home directory, or to `/tmp`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In comments you say you're trying to put the files in "the root directory". It's unclear if this is `/` or `/root`, but in any case, writing to any of these two directories require root permissions, and I'm suspecting that you don't log in as root with winscp (you don't tell).

You really only need to offload the files on your SuSE system *somewhere*. Later, if the files needs to be in some specific place, you may log in on the machine and, as root, move the files to wherever you need them to be.

Two suggestions for where to put the files:

1. In the `/tmp` directory.  All users have the ability to create files there.
2. In the home directory of the user that you use to connect with winscp as.  The user trivially has write permissions in their own home directory.

As for *how* to do this, I don't know, as I've never used winscp and don't know how it works.

With ordinary OpenSSH `scp`, you would do

```
scp the files username@hostname:
```

where `the files` are the names of the files that you need to transfer.  This would put the files in the home directory of the `username` user on the host `hostname`.  Using `...hostname:/tmp` at the end would put the files in the `/tmp` directory.